# FakeItEasy - I cannot see if a protected method was called when the caller method is protected overriden

Tags: unit-testing, fakeiteasy

I'm new to FakeItEasy, sorry if the solution is obvious.

This is the simplified code which reproduces the problem:

I have a base class:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
    {
        public void Do()
        {
            Do_Override();
        }

        protected abstract void Do_Override();
    }
```

and a derived one:

```
  public class ImplementingClass: BaseClass
    {
        protected override void Do_Override()
        {
            ProtectedDo();
        }

        protected virtual void ProtectedDo()
        {

        }        
    }
```

In my test I want to see if `ProtectedDo()` was called. I've tried to test in two ways, but tests are failing with the same message:

1st. In debug mode it is not entering in `Do_Override()`

```
 public class ImplementingClassShould
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Run_ProtectedDo()
        {
            var fake = A.Fake<ImplementingClass>();
            fake.Do();
            A.CallTo(fake).Where(_ => _.Method.Name == "ProtectedDo").MustHaveHappened();

        }
     }
```

2nd. In debug mode it is entering in `Do_Override()`

```
 public class ImplementingClassShould
    {    
        [Fact]
        public void Run_ProtectedDo_V2()
        {
            var sut = new ImplementingClass();
            var sutFakeWrapper = A.Fake<ImplementingClass>(_ => _.Wrapping(sut));
            sutFakeWrapper.Do();
            A.CallTo(sutFakeWrapper).Where(_ => _.Method.Name == "ProtectedDo").MustHaveHappened();

        }        
    }
```

Fail message:

[image]

Comment: Hi, @fmm. I like the simplified repro, but it's generally a good idea to indicate what went wrong in your experience. For example, why don't you think your code is working?

Comment: Hi, @BlairConrad. I've update my question with the message of test failing. Also my 2nd try to test. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is perfectly good, as far as it goes. If you run it, it'll tell you that `ProtectedDo` was not called, which is accurate. Because `Do_Override` is virtual, FakeItEasy intercepts the call. (The protectedness doesn't affect things in this case.)

If you don't want `Do_Override` to be intercepted by FakeItEasy, you should configure the Fake to [call the base method](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/calling-base-methods/) instead of handling the call itself:

```cs
[Fact]
public void Run_ProtectedDo()
{
    var fake = A.Fake<ImplementingClass>();

    A.CallTo(fake).Where(_ => _.Method.Name == "Do_Override").CallsBaseMethod();

    fake.Do();
    A.CallTo(fake).Where(_ => _.Method.Name == "ProtectedDo").MustHaveHappened();

}
```

---

**Update in light of the newly added `Run_ProtectedDo_V2` test:**

I expect you know this already, @fmm, but the test still fails. This is because when `sutFakeWrapper.Do` is called, it forwards to the wrapped `sut.Do`. Since `sut` is a concrete `ImplementingClass`, it calls its `Do_Override`, which calls its `ProtectedDo`, so it's possible to debug into a `ProtectedDo` method call. Only it's `sut.ProtectedDo`, not `sutFakeWrapper.ProtectedDo`. Hence the test failure.